# Flowbite modals are not working after using pagination [Livewire3]

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, flowbite

I'm learning how to use Livewire. All modals on the table's first page are working fine. But after you use the pagination, the modals are not working anymore. I added console.log to check if I'm hitting the right toggle, and it shows the proper ID but not the modal.

[My Views/Livewire Component](https://codefile.io/f/G7CVRZAJl5#)

```
<div>
<div class="overflow-x-auto sm:rounded-lg p-2">
    <table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
        <thead class="text-xs text-gray-50 uppercase bg-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-1">
                    Id
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-1">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    Email
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    Created At
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $item)
                <tr class="bg-gray-300 border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                    <th scope="row"
                        class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                        {{ $item->id }}
                    </th>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                        {{ $item->name }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                        {{ $item->email }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                        {{ $item->created_at }}
                    </td>

                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                        <button data-modal-target="popup-modal-{{$item->id}}" data-modal-toggle="popup-modal-{{$item->id}}" class="block text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button">
                            Toggle modal
                            </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    {{$users->links()}}

    @foreach ($users as $item)
    <div id="popup-modal-{{$item->id}}" tabindex="-1" class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-50 justify-center items-center w-full md:inset-0 h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full">
        <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-md max-h-full">
            <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
                <button type="button" class="absolute top-3 end-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 ms-auto inline-flex justify-center items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-hide="popup-modal-{{$item->id}}">
                    <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"/>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                </button>
                <div class="p-4 md:p-5 text-center">
                    <svg class="mx-auto mb-4 text-gray-400 w-12 h-12 dark:text-gray-200" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 11V6m0 8h.01M19 10a9 9 0 1 1-18 0 9 9 0 0 1 18 0Z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <h3 class="mb-5 text-lg font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Are you sure you want to delete this product? - {{$item->id}}</h3>
                    <button data-modal-hide="popup-modal-{{$item->id}}" type="button" class="text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-300 dark:focus:ring-red-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-center me-2">
                        Yes, I'm sure
                    </button>
                    <button data-modal-hide="popup-modal-{{$item->id}}" type="button" class="text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-200 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 hover:text-gray-900 focus:z-10 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-600">No, cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach

</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-toggle]');

        buttons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const buttonId = this.getAttribute('data-modal-target');
                console.log('Clicked button ID:', buttonId);
                // Additional code for toggling modal visibility if needed
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not an image.

Answer (score 1):

OK! I know this one!

The problem is that on every pagination event Livewire is removing all the elements from the DOM and replacing them with new elements.

You click a pagination button and all the buttons which had modal listeners bound are deleted from the DOM, then when you click the new items, they do not have listeners bound! So how to fix this problem?

```
Livewire.hook('morph.updated', ({ el, component }) => {
    //use el to check if this item is the modal button and bind the event handler here
});
```

Not sure about the flowbite JS package so that's up in the air but here is an approach that should work for all elements in the body.

```
// Event delegation
function eventDelegator(selector, eventType, childSelector, eventHandler){
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (element of elements) {
    element.addEventListener(eventType, (eventOnElement) => {
      if (eventOnElement.target.closest(childSelector)) {
        eventHandler(eventOnElement);
      }
    });
  }
};
// call like this
eventDelegator("body", "click", '[data-modal-toggle]', (event) => {
  const modal = document.querySelector(event.target.dataset.target);
  showModal(modal);
});
```